# Unbale load url in webview android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

I try load another url in class MyJavaScriptInterface but is not work

this code is for load url.

```
class MyJavaScriptInterface
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void processHTML(String html)
    {
        Log.e("processHTML::",html);
        Log.e("url2::",url2);
        if (html.contains("class")){
            Log.e("<span class::","yes");
            browser.loadUrl(url2);

        }else {
            PRB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }
}
```

This log is displayed  :

```
 Log.e("<span class::","yes");
```

and this Condition is ok :

```
 if (html.contains("class")){
```

my code java :

```
    package chindi.ir.chindi;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView browser;
    private WebSettings webSettings;
    private RelativeLayout PRB;
    private Boolean showJS,isFirst,isSs,isFirst2;
    private String url="http://www.chindi.ir";
    private String url2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView);
        PRB=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.kkk);
        WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        showJS =extras.getBoolean("jsload",false);
        isSs =extras.getBoolean("isSs",false);
        url2=extras.getString("urlload2");
        browser.loadUrl(extras.getString("urlload"));
        isFirst=true;
        isFirst2=true;
        class MyJavaScriptInterface
        {
            @JavascriptInterface
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public void processHTML(String html)
            {
                Log.e("processHTML::",html);
                Log.e("url2::",url2);
                if (html.contains("class")){
                    Log.e("<span class::","yes");
                    browser.loadUrl(url2);

                }else {
                    PRB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
        browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
              //  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (url.endsWith(".m00000p4")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/mp4"); view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    view.loadUrl(url);
                } return true;
            }
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {
                Log.e("onPageFinished::",url);
                Log.e("isSs::",isSs.toString());
                Log.e("isFirst2::",isFirst2.toString());
                if(showJS&&isFirst) {
                    isFirst=false;
                    browser.loadUrl("javascript:geoFindMe()");
                }
                if (isSs&&isFirst2){
                    isFirst2=false;
                    browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(document.getElementById('select2-w0-container').innerHTML);");

                }else {
                    PRB.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            }
            public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
            {
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
            {
                // TODO show you progress image
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                if (url.equals("https://chindi.ir/")|url.equals("https://chindi.ir")|url.equals("https://www.chindi.ir/")|url.equals("https://www.chindi.ir")|url.equals("http://chindi.ir/")|url.equals("http://chindi.ir")) {
                    finish();
                }else {
                    PRB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }

            }

        });
    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (browser.canGoBack()) {
            browser.goBack();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not calling browser.loadUrl(url2) from main thread.
You could try:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            browser.loadUrl(url2);
        }
    });
```